# Overloading operator= breaks std::sort

Tags: c++, c++11, assignment-operator

Probably a dupe, but I can't find it.

After two days of nunchucking my keyboard, I have discovered that overloading the equals operator (`operator=`) apparently breaks `std::sort`.  Maybe I'm overloading `operator=` incorrectly?  This is my MCVE:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

struct Person
{
  std::string name;
  uint32_t age;

  bool operator< (const Person& p)
  {
    return this->age < p.age;
  }

  Person operator= (const Person& p)
  {
    Person newP;
    newP.name = p.name;
    newP.age = p.age;

    return newP;
  }

  static bool SortPeople(const Person& p1, const Person& p2)
  {
    return p1.age < p2.age;
  }
};

void PrintPeople(const std::vector<Person>& people)
{
  std::cout << "============ people begin" << std::endl;
  for (const auto& pIt : people)
  {
    std::cout << "name: " << pIt.name << ", age: " << pIt.age << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "============ people end" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Person> people = { { "james", 12 },
                                 { "jada", 4   },
                                 { "max", 44   },
                                 { "bart", 7   }
                               };

  PrintPeople(people);


  std::sort(people.begin(), people.end());
  PrintPeople(people);  

  return 0;
}
```

If I run this code as is, each person is *not* sorted based on age.  `PrintPeople` prints out in the same order that I initialized `people` in.  However, if I comment out the entire `Person operator=` function, then `people` *does* get printed out in ascending order based on age.  I see this same behavior whether I call `std::sort(people.begin(), people.end());` or `std::sort(people.begin(), people.end(), Person::SortPeople);`, and I see this same behavior whether I use `g++` version 7.2.1 or `clang++` version 4.0.1.  I'm running Fedora 27.

Anyone have any idea *why* overloading `operator=` breaks `std::sort`?

I'm compiling with flags `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c++11`,, there are no warnings.

Comment: Your assignment operator doesn't assign at all. It just returns a new thing. The purpose of an assignment operator is to modify the instance it's called so that it has the same state at the object it's being assigned from. It should modify `this` and not some new instance.

Comment: Note that the default assignment operator will work just fine in `Person`'s case. You're getting in your own way by defining it here.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks a lot, makes sense!

Comment: `a = b` is supposed to change `a`, and it is reasonable to expect `std::sort` will assume that.  Your definition of `operator=()` does not behave correctly.

Comment: Also, remember the rule of three - if it is necessary to provide a copy constructor, a `operator=()`, or a destructor, it is usually necessary to provide all three.    In C++11 and later, the rule of three may become the "rule of five".   Also look up "rule of zero".

Comment: Thanks @Peter .. never heard of those, I'll definitely take a look.

Comment: It seems nobody has yet mentioned that "equals operator" is a very wrong term here, because it sounds like `operator==` and not `operator=`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl you're right,, assignment operator?

Comment: @yano: Yes, "assignment operator" is the correct word.

Comment: @ChristianHackl fair enough, assignment operator it is then. I will decontaminate tomorrow when I can think better.

Comment: @yano Perhaps even so far as to say "copy assignment operator" in order to distinguish it from the "move assignment operator" (C++11).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you're overloading `operator=` wrongly. It's supposed to modify on `*this`, but you're modifying on a local object `newP`.

Change it to

```
Person& operator= (const Person& p)
{
  name = p.name;
  age = p.age;

  return *this;
}
```

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) sorts elements by moving them, which uses the overloaded `operator=` for `Person`. That's why the wrong implementation breaks `std::sort` here.

BTW: When you remove the implementation, the auto-generated assignment operator does the right thing for you.

Comment: `Person& operator= (const Person& p)&` is better

Comment: @Yakk Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I was this close `-->| |<--` to playing with `this` in this function before I asked,, shame on me. Thanks a lot this works perfectly. Yes @Yakk I'm curious too.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux To prevent from assignment on a temporary object, like built-in types.

Comment: The OP should not change his or her overloaded `operator=` but *remove* it entirely, because it's completely redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Your `operator=` overload is fundamentally broken: it returns a **new** object (instead of a reference to `*this`, as is the strong convention) without affecting `*this` at all.